# Altair regression transform with params=True: how to access r² and coeffs when having multiple groups

Tags: python, regression, grouping, altair

I am using `transform_regression` to create a regression line and the corresponding equation text in the chart. For a single regression this works fine, but with set `groupby=['something']` option, the texts get plotted on top of each other.

I tried constructing the string using `lineBreak='\n'` but that didn't help.
Also it is creating a own color group for the equations named `undefined`, which is not very practical. Any way to avoid this? I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665596/how-to-label-the-line-from-transform-regression-using-altair) question, but I don't want to change the name, I'd prefer to not give it an own entry at all.

Here is an example:

```py
import altair as alt
import altair_transform
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
x = np.linspace(0, 10)
y = np.e ** (-0.1 *x)  + np.random.randn(len(x)) / 5
group = np.random.choice(['a','b'],len(x))

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'group': group})
df.loc[df.group == 'a', 'y'] *= 0.1 

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x='x',
    y= alt.Y('y',scale = alt.Scale(type= 'log')),
    color= 'group')

Reg_Line = chart.transform_regression('x', 'y',
                                      method="exp",
                                      groupby=["group"]
).mark_line()

Reg_Params = chart.transform_regression('x', 'y',
                                     method="exp",
                                     groupby=["group"],
                                     params=True   
).mark_text(align='left', lineBreak='\n'
).encode(
    x=alt.value(150),  # pixels from left
    y=alt.value(250),  # pixels from top
    text='params:N'
).transform_calculate(
    params='"r² = " + round(datum.rSquared * 100)/100 + \
    "      y = " + round(datum.coef[0] * 10)/10 + " + e ^ (" + \
    round(datum.coef[1] * 10000)/10000 + "x" + ")" + \n + " "')

chart + Reg_Line + Reg_Params
```

[image: plot]

Comment: hey @roble, did you find the solution to this problem by any chance?

Comment: @ariera no, not yet, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

**!! This only addresses a part of the question !!**

*If I find a solution to the rest of the problem I will modify this answer.*

While I haven't found a way to resolve placement of texts on top of each other, here is at least something that suppresses the extra legend entry:

- add a color encoding to the line chart and the text chart and set their legend option to `None`
- resolve the colors of the compound with `independent`

This is a modification of the above example:

```py
import altair as alt
import altair_transform
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
x = np.linspace(0, 10)
y = np.e ** (-0.1 *x)  + np.random.randn(len(x)) / 5
group = np.random.choice(['a','b'],len(x))

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'group': group})
df.loc[df.group == 'a', 'y'] *= 0.1 

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x='x',
    y= alt.Y('y',scale = alt.Scale(type= 'log')),
    color= 'group')

Reg_Line = chart.transform_regression('x', 'y',
                                      method="exp",
                                      groupby=["group"]
).mark_line().encode(color=alt.Color('group', legend=None))

Reg_Params = chart.transform_regression('x', 'y',
                                     method="exp",
                                     groupby=["group"],
                                     params=True   
).mark_text(align='left', lineBreak='\n'
).encode(
    x=alt.value(150),  # pixels from left
    y=alt.value(250),  # pixels from top
    color=alt.Color('group', legend=None),
    text='params:N'
).transform_calculate(
    params='"r² = " + round(datum.rSquared * 100)/100 + \
    "      y = " + round(datum.coef[0] * 10)/10 + " + e ^ (" + \
    round(datum.coef[1] * 10000)/10000 + "x" + ")" + \n + " "')

(chart + Reg_Line + Reg_Params).resolve_scale(color='independent')
```

Comment: What I have tried to disentangle the text placements is adding another column to the `df` which holds values for the y-encodings of the `mark_text`. The values of that column are 250 (what I use in the example as a fixed y value) for one group, and 230 for the other. So I would expect the texts to be off-set by 20 pixels. However, it didn't show any texts in this case and neither did it when I created a mean aggregation on that column with `groupby=['group']` and used that instead of the column values themselves. Any hints welcome!