# Altair - Undefined Color Legend when adding a Regression Line

Tags: altair

Altair added an undefined color legend after Regression line is added.
It looks like because the regression line introduced a new color to the chart.

[image: Altair Undefined Color Legend]

I have tried to change the Regression line color by adding color parameter to mark_line(color="red"),
but it would not work (regression line color did not change to red).
I will be grateful for any help.

Below is my code:

```
test = alt.Chart(sortedGNI).mark_circle().encode(
    alt.X('CO2 Emission:Q', title="CO2 Emission per Capita 2019"),
    alt.Y('Human Development Index:Q'),
    alt.Color('GNI cat:O',  scale=alt.Scale(scheme='redyellowgreen'),
             sort=["Very High GNI", "High GNI", "Mid GNI", "Low GNI"],
             title=["Gross National Income ", "Per Capita"]),
    tooltip = ['Country:N', 'Gross National Income Per Capita:Q', 'Human Development Index:Q', 'CO2 Emission:Q']
)

test + test.transform_regression("CO2 Emission", "Human Development Index", method="pow").mark_line()
```

Comment: I solved this using tranform_fold(), adding a new color category in the Legend for the regression line. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665596/how-to-label-the-line-from-transform-regression-using-altair

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well:

```
test + test.transform_regression("CO2 Emission", 
    "Human Development Index", method="pow").mark_line().encode(color = 
     alt.Color(legend=None))
```